# Disabling Windows 8.1 screen orientation key shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

When pressing CTRL + ALT + up/down/left/right, everything on my screen rotates to 90 degrees, -90 or 180 (upside down). Can I disable these shortcuts so I can use them for something else?

Comment: Do you have Intel graphics?

Comment: Yes, I see that those key shortcut (CTRL + ALT + arrows) were set there. I disabled them, so now the shortcuts do nothing. But I still can't use them in my applications! Simply says I can't use these... Any suggestion?

Comment: @drake035 in what applications you can't use them? For example, I disabled the hot keys (right click->graphics options->hot keys->disable ) to use the CTRL+ALT+LEFT/RIGHTin Intellij Idea and it worked. Maybe is an application related issue

Comment: Some browsers, like Firefox and Chrome/Chromium don't let you use some key combinations.  Not entirely sure why.  I've found it frustrating sometimes because I wanted to assign some shortcuts to NoScript and couldn't because of this restriction.  Perhaps it's time I had a look through the source code for a reason 

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling them, define other shortcuts to rotate the screen. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + arrows will then be free for something else.